# Let $p \neq \pm 1, 0$ be an integer. Prove that $p$ is prime iff for all $a \in \mathbb Z$, either $p \mid a$ or $(a, p) = 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'll try in $\to$ direction;

Nothing divides the prime $p$ but $\pm1, \pm p$. If $a = \pm p$ or $a = \pm 1$ then $p \mid a$.

Assume $p = 2$ . If $a$ is even, then $p \mid a$ and if $a$ is odd, then  $(a, p) = 1$.

Suppose $p > 2$. If $a$ is even, then $(a, p) = 1$ since $2$ is the only even prime integer. Suppose $a$ is odd. Then $a$ is either prime or not. If $a$ is prime, then $(a, p) = 1$. If $a$ is not prime, then $a$ is either positive/negative multiple of $p$ or not. If it's the former $p \mid a$, otherwise $(a, p) = 1$.

How can I improve it?

Comment: Your statement " If a is even, then (a,p)=1 since 2 is the only even prime integer." is false.  Take $p=3$ and $a = 6$.

Comment: In that case do we say either $a$ is a multiple of $p$ or not? Is there a better, more compact proof?

Comment: I'll do the $\Rightarrow$ direction, leave the other to you.  Suppose $p$ is a prime.  Then, look at $(a,p)$.  of course, we have $(a,p)|p$ and since $p$ is prime that means that $(a,p)$ is either $1$ or $p$.  If it is $1$ we are done, so say it is $p$. But of course we also have $(a,p)|a$ so this would mean $p|a$ so again we are done.

Comment: Very nice. I had another thought. If $p \mid a$, we are done. Suppose $p$ doesn't divide $a$. Let $q \neq p \in \mathbb Z$ such that $q \mid a$. But then $q$ doesn't divide $p$, so $(a, p) = 1.$ Would something like that work?

Comment: You are trying to prove $\Leftarrow$ now?

Comment: No. I was just trying to see what else I could do in $\to$ direction in addition to what you wrote.

Comment: Never mind, I see you are trying for another proof of $\Rightarrow$.  But, I don't think it works.  What is $q$ ?  you need an argument for all $a$ not just primes.

Comment: Ok...I see what you are saying. If you  know Unique Factorization, you can reason this way.  Fair enough.

Comment: Than you very much, lulu. I'll go try the other direction.

Comment: If $(a, p) = 1$, then $p$ is not necessarily prime because $(9, 4) = 1$. If $p \mid a$ and $p$ is prime we're done. Suppose $p$ is composite. Then $a$ can't be prime, so $a$ is composite. But then we can reduce both $p, a$ to their prime versions. So $p$ is prime. ?

Comment: Not following.  My sense is that in this direction ($\Leftarrow$) it is easier to prove the contrapositive.  That is, given that we want to show $A\Leftarrow B$ prove instead that $not\,B\Leftarrow not\,A$  Therefore, assume that $p$ is not a prime.  Find an $a$ such that neither $p|a$ nor $(a,p)=1$.

Comment: How about this: Let $ax + py = 1$. Then $pax + ppy = p$. Since $p \mid a$, we have $p | pax$ and since $p \mid p$, we have $p \mid ppy$. Further, $p \mid (pax + ppy)$. So, $p \mid p$. So then $p$ must be prime.

Comment: What are you assuming here?  It looks like you are saying that BOTH $(a,p)=1$ and $p|a$.  That is not possible.  If $p|a$ then $(a,p)=p$.

Comment: All you need to prove is this:  if $p>1$ is not a prime, then there is at least one number $a$ such that neither $(a,p)=1$ nor does $p|a$.  Try an example.  Suppose $p=6$..Can you find an $a$ that works in this particular case?

Comment: Can we let $a = 3$?

Comment: Absolutely.  Good.  Can you now do the general case?

Comment: So we showed the second part is true for $p > 1$. Can we say since $p > 1$ is prime $-p < -1$ is also prime?

Comment: Not really.  I think the problem only makes sense for positive $p$.  That is, you are meant to be showing that $|p|$ is prime.   It's a bad idea to let negative numbers be prime...messes up Unique Factorization, for example.  As $6=2^*3=(-2)^*(-3)$.

Comment: Ok, I might've misunderstood you. What's general case? Didn't we show p is prime?

Comment: We showed $6$ didn't work!  but now you have to repeat the argument for every composite $p$.  How to do that may be clear to you at this point, but I didn't see it written out.

Comment: I failed to find such $a$. $(a, p) = 1$ means $a \neq \pm 1, \pm p$  doesn't divide $p$. So, the only integers that divide $p$ are $\pm 1, \pm p$, but isn't that the definition of prime?

Comment: Well, look at what worked for $6$. You chose $a=3$, a factor of $6$.  Similarly, if $p$ is not a prime, then we can write $p=m^*n$ for integers $m,n>1$.  Try one of those.

Comment: Let $a = m$. Then $(a, p) = m$ and $p$ doesn't divide $a$. Seems like we're done?

Comment: That works.  Good!

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is a summary of the argument sorted out in the comments.

We will take $p>1$.  If $p<-1$ then the arguments below show that $|p|$ is a prime, which is what I assume the question intends.

First, let's show $p$ prime $\Rightarrow$ either $(a,p)=1$ or $p|a$

Pf: We will use the fact that, for any integers $m,n$ $(m,n)|m$ and $(m,n)|n$.  In this case, we note that $(a,p)|p\Rightarrow (a,p)=1\;or\;(a,p)=p$.  In the first case, we are done at once.  In the second we are done once we note that $(a,p)|a$.

Now, the opposite implication.

Pf:  It is easier to show the contrapositive, so suppose that $p$ is not a prime. We need to show that the right hand statement is false.  We write $p=mn$ where $m,n$ are integers, both greater than $1$. Then taking $a=m$ gives the desired contradiction and, again, we are done.

Comment: Good. Much more readable than the comment thread ;)